# FastAPI response model list of json objects

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I am using MongoDB and FastAPI but can't get my response for more than one document to render without an error, it's a lack of understanding on my part but no matter what I read, I can't seem to get to the bottom of it?

**models.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr, Field

    #Class for a user
    class User(BaseModel):
       username: constr(to_lower=True)
       _id: str = Field(..., alias='id')
       name: str
       isActive : bool
       weekPlan : str

    #Example to provide on FastAPI Docs
    class Config:

        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        orm_mode = True
        schema_extra = {

        "example": {
            "name": "John Smith",
            "username": "john@smith.com",
            "isActive": "true",
            "weekPlan": "1234567",
        }
    }
```

**routes.py**

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, HTTPException, status, Response

from models.user import User
from config.db import dbusers

user = APIRouter()    

@user.get('/users', tags=["users"], response_model=list[User])
         async def find_all_users(response: Response):
         # Content-Range needed for react-admin
         response.headers['Content-Range'] = '4'
         response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'content-range'
         users = (dbusers.find())
         return users
```

**mongodb json data**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("62b325f65402e5ceea8a4b6f")
  },
  "name": "John Smith",
  "isActive": true,
  "weekPlan": "1234567"
   },
   {
    "_id" : ObjectId("62b325f65402e5ceea9a3d4c"),
    "username" : "john@smith.com",
    "name" : "John Smith",
    "isActive" : true,
    "weekPlan" : "1234567"
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 670, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 266, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 65, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 235, in app
    response_data = await serialize_response(
  File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\venv\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 138, in serialize_response
    raise ValidationError(errors, field.type_)
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
response
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What error are you getting? You probably want `List` imported from Typing as well (at least that's the usual typehint for lists).

Comment: Ah I am using the python list rather than 'List' from typing as that give me another error to troubleshoot. 

 File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\.\index.py", line 2, in <module>
    from routes.user import user
  File "C:\Git2\thrive-app-react\backend\.\routes\user.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Typing import List
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Typing'. Even though I imported it using pip. 


I have updated my original post with the original error I get. Thanks for helping

Comment: Sorry for confusing you; the module is named `typing`: `from typing import List` - It's part of the standard library, you should not install it through `pip`.

Comment: Oh I understand - my fault. so I have that import now and have also switched from 'list' to 'List'. However I still get the same error

pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
response
  value is not a valid list (type=type_error.list)

Comment: I'm not familiar with pymongo, but attaching a debugger at the `return users` line and looking at what `users` actually is might be helpful. I'm guessing it might not be represented as an actual list, but an internal pymongo query result or an iterator of some sort? According to the docs: "Returns an instance of Cursor corresponding to this query." Seems you can convert it to a list by simply wrapping `list()` around it.

Comment: You absolute legend!! Where did you find the list() part in the docs just so I know for next time? Do you want to put it as an official answer for me to mark up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pymongo's `find` method returns a Cursor - you have to exhaust this iterator first, since Pydantic doesn't have any idea what it should do with a Cursor object.

You can do this by giving it as an argument to `list`:

```py
@user.get('/users', tags=["users"], response_model=List[User])
async def find_all_users(response: Response):
    ...
    return list(dbusers.find())
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on, thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks so much. `List` is exatly what I am looking for.